# How do I pass a value into a python function without calling?

Tags: python, function, parameters

I was unable to find a reasonable way to create a variable which calls a function requiring parameters.

Here is a simplified version of my code.  I would like `print_hello` to print `hello` when it is called, and not when it is defined.

```
print_hello = print('hello')
```

When I define `print_hello`, it calls `print('hello')`.  When I call `print_hello`, it gives me an error.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just define `print_hello` as a lambda function

```
>>> print_hello = lambda: print('hello')
>>> print_hello()
hello
```

To delay execution, you'll have to wrap the call to `print` in another function. A lambda is less code than defining another function.

**Note:** that [pep08](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends using a def function rather than a lambda when assigning to a variable. See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). So @Sheldores [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56435591/1540468) is probably the way to go.

Comment: Although, this ends up with a named lambda, which is against PEP8

Comment: ah ok I never knew that. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: <shrug> That's up to you. It does the job and I suspect the op has an X/Y Problem. Let me find the reference

Answer (score 11):

If you just want a function that does precisely what you describe, [Sheldore's answer is the simplest way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56435591/364696) (and more Pythonic than using a named `lambda`).

An alternative approach is to [make a partial application of the function with `functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which allows you to pass additional arguments at call time:

```
from functools import partial

print_hello = partial(print, "hello")

print_hello()  # Prints "hello" to stdout

print_hello(file=sys.stderr)  # Prints "hello" to stderr

print_hello("world")  # Prints "hello world" to stdout
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a function. In python a function is defined using `def` as shown in a simple example for your purpose below. You then call the function using the function name and `()`, for instance `print_hello()`.

```
def print_hello(): # <--- Does not accept an argument 
    print('hello')

print_hello()    # <--- No argument is passed
# hello
```

Another example to give you more idea on how to pass an argument to the function. You can define a variable that contains the string you want to print, let's say `to_print` and then pass this as an argument to your function during calling it. While explaining more details is out of the scope of this answer, the two examples I gave should get you started. For more details, you can refer to the official docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

```
def print_hello(to_print): # <--- Accepts an argument 
        print(to_print)

to_print = "hello"
print_hello(to_print) # <--- Argument is passed
# hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `lambda` expression:

```
print_hello = lambda: print('hello')
```

Or an actual function definition:

```
def print_hello(): print('hello')
```

Or `functools.partial` *(this is different in that you can still use other arguments for `print` whereas you lose that functionality with the others unless specified in the definitions)*

```
from functools import partial
print_hello = partial(print, 'hello')
```

To use any of these:

```
print_hello()
#'hello'
```