# apply rotation function of Numpy randomly in python

Tags: python, numpy

I did a following code.
I want to apply a `np.rot90` randomly on images.

this question is might not similar to [How do I pass a value into a python function without calling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435569/how-do-i-pass-a-value-into-a-python-function-without-calling)

if you think so, kindly help me with that.

```
images = [np.random.randint(100, size=(120, 120)) for _ in range(10)]

my_list = [lambda x: x,np.rot90, np.rot90(x,k=2),np.rot90(x,k=3)]

a=[random.choice(my_list)(image) for image in images]
```

it returns the error `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

but when i did `my_list = [lambda x: x,np.rot90, np.rot90]` it does not show that error. however this is not i want to do.

how can i solve this probleM?

Comment: You did `np.rot90(x, k=2)` which is a function call, and `x` is undefined there. You want to create a new function where `k=2` is already set, see the linked duplicate.

Comment: i dont know how this question is connected to that. could you help me with that if you know how to do it.  if i want to apply 180 degree , i should pass k=2 in `np.rot90`. that is why i put k=2. if you know any alternative sol, let me know. Thanks @AndrasDeak

Comment: One possible solution is `partial(np.rot90, k=3)`. Like the top answer says, but in your case you want to bind a keyword argument. This will be a function which you can later call. Notice how there's no `x` in it.

Comment: Hi, you just need to change the code a bit

my_list = [lambda x: x, lambda x: np.rot90(x), lambda x: np.rot90(x, k=2), lambda x: np.rot90(x, k=3)]

Comment: or
    `def manytimes(x):
        return x, np.rot90(x), np.rot90(x, k=2), np.rot90(x, k=3)

    my_list = [manytimes(image) for image in images]`

Comment: @B.Kocis Thanks